# Jetty has a timeout exception loading the war

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

it's a very basic example.
I wanted to load the web application using jetty like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8085);    
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext( "D:/workspace/camel/TestWithGradle/src/main/java/sample.war" , "sample");
    webapp.setExtractWAR(true);
    webapp.setParentLoaderPriority(true);


    server.setHandler(webapp);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

And the war is https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy/blob/master/spec/resources/sample-war.war
it's very simple war that uses jsp files and java servlet.

But, I run this application, the console gave the exception..

```
2014-11-24 23:52:49.528:INFO::main: Logging initialized @333ms
2014-11-24 23:52:49.689:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.5.v20140505
2014-11-24 23:53:11.779:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@364de63{sample,file:/C:/Users/SDS/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8085-sample.war-sample-any-853618354381316480.dir/webapp/,null}{D:/workspace/camel/TestWithGradle/src/main/java/sample.war}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:637)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1290)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1164)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:964)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setWebXml(MetaData.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at TestServer.main(TestServer.java:21)
2014-11-24 23:53:11.874:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5054a835{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8085}
2014-11-24 23:53:11.875:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @22829ms
```

Please, help me with the elaborate explanation. thanks for reading and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have an XML with a bad DTD or namespace declaration.

The startup is attempting to fetch some sort of resource from a remote URL that would be used in validating the XML.

This will not happen with a normal jetty distribution, or the normal jetty jar artifacts.

Start with making sure you are using the official jetty jars, don't repackage them, don't uberjar them, don't one-jar them, leave them alone (for now).

Then make sure you have no typos in your various XML files.  Especially in your war file, and all of the contents of the  `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` files.  There is likely a small typo or reference that is incorrect enough that Jetty can't shortcut that remote resource request with the validation resources that comes with the jetty jars.

Comment: I already loaded this war with tomcat putting war into webapp directory in tomcat.

Comment: Irrelevant.  Tomcat might not validate their XML.  or the Tomcat installation you were using has the missing resource that Jetty does not.